# Best practice to import user base (subscribers) from one website to another?

Tags: database, users, wpdb, import, export

I want to import users from a Wordpress installation to another.

Same domain, but complete different websites.

- **Website A** (old, 700 users): running **WP3.0** plain installation + **BBPress 1**.x
- **Website B** (new, no users): **WP3.3.1** *MULTISITE* installation + **BBPress 2**.0 + **Buddypress 1.5.4**

*database will change as well, Website B will use a new database - therefore the table prefixes won't match*

**what's the best practice to import user base from website A to website B in this scenario?** I wish users could retain their login data and passwords. Many of them have created topics and discussions in BB1.0 they need to *retain* the ownership of their forum topics in BB2.0.

BB2.0 has a built in importer but in a localhost enviroment refuses to import users for some reason (seems to work ok for forums/topics/replies). I'm trying BBConverter plugin but also has problems (hangs halfway, not matter what settings I have in php.ini). For bare users, I've also found a plugin called CIMY User Manager... but exports users in a CSV file, then imports them back. However it doesn't save passwords, so all users need to ask for new ones, I wish to avoid inconvenients like this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup your Website B, add a user through the control panel, then view what tables in the database they were added to and what extra fields were set. Then use Navicat or phpmyadmin to dump users from Website B into excel, combine the users from Website A, set any missing fields then import to Website B

Comment: I see.. would this allow users to retain their passwords though? I'm going to figure out in the next days, try and report on this thread, thanks

Comment: Most likely yes because if the passwords were MD5 hashed you just need to copy / paste that field from the old db table to the new db table.

Comment: Great glad I could help, i'm sure it wasn't to hard just a few table fields to export and import